# How can I include/require foreign JavaScript libraries in WordPress?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-maps

I am writing an interactive google map in javascript for a wordpress page. As far as I know, the only way to use javascript with wordpress is by creating a separate .js file and just calling the methods from there within the wordpress page. So my question is, if I need to use the google maps api in my javascript code, how do I 'include' it within the .js file instead of using a `<script>` tag in the html?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there is no `include` in javascript. Take a look at [wp_enqueue_script()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script).

**Edit**

Just stumbled over the [yepnope.js library](http://yepnopejs.com/) by Alex Sexton. Maybe this is what you are looking for.

Comment: this may be helpful as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/include-javascript-file-inside-javascript-file

Comment: can I use `wp_enqueue_script()` within the html in the online interface for editing a wordpress page?

Comment: As long as you can edit PHP code there I don't see why not. I never used the online interface.